# Link Javascript file of a Class Library (.net) to blazor app

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor

I am currently working on a VS 2019 solution made of two projects: **One is a class library containing a Javascript file, the other is a Blazor .Net Core project (client-side).**

I am looking to reference the script in my class library to my blazor app in order to call its functions from the client-side.

I am aware I could simply add the file directly into the blazor project but I am looking for other ways to implement the Js file, specifically from a .Net class library.

Comment: The question is a little confusing. A class library, in .NET terms, is a DLL which has compiled code that is available for use by other .NET assemblies. A JavaScript file is a text file with code that needs to be parsed and interpreted by a JavaScript engine. Two separate ideas. You could, theoretically, embed the JavaScript file as a resource within a .NET DLL, load it in Blazor, then expose it to the browser for parsing and interpretation, but that's a lot of work and complication when you could just link to the file in your Blazor app...

Comment: I'm looking to make a project with my javascript file that a web app could reference like jquery or bootstrap.

Comment: Try creating a project using the template `Razor Class Library` in Visual Studio. It will create a sample project with an example of JavaScript interop using an included javascript file.

Comment: @hultqvist How is it misleading to describe the current state of Blazor? Or how JavaScript is interpreted by the browser? Also, the given answer is doing exactly what I described in my comment.

Comment: @HereticMonkey My bad, I was thining about [static assets in razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#build-pack-and-ship-to-nuget) but I now see that was published after your initial comment.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to add the js file to the Blazor project like you said. For a slightly more maintanable solution, consider creating a *Razor* class library ("RCL") instead of a .Net class library, as it supports referencing static assets (see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/class-libraries) and more specifically [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-an-rcl-with-static-assets) for instructions).

There is also the much more complicated way of "streaming" your js file from the resource file of your .Net Library. The advantage is that a normal .Net standard class library will do, and you don't need to reference the script with a `script` tag. You can implement this by referencing your js file as an embedded resource like this (in the .csproj of your .Net class library):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="wwwroot\script\MyJs.js" 
                      LogicalName="blazor:js:%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and then invoke js with the contents of your file using eval:

```
// Get contents of resource
string scriptContent;
using (var stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("blazor:js:MyJs.js"))
{
  using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
    scriptContent = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
  }
}

JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<T>("eval", scriptContent)
```

Full-fledged example of the last strategy [here](https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorFileReader/blob/d58a39029dfcb526350da76eaaad90c51f137f6d/src/Blazor.FileReader/Blazor.FileReader.csproj#L37) (and [here](https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorFileReader/blob/d58a39029dfcb526350da76eaaad90c51f137f6d/src/Blazor.FileReader/FileReaderJsInterop.cs#L145)) (Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer).